# Test class data missing?

Tags: unit-test, if

I have a couple of days with this test class.
I added already all data necessary for my test class, but I'm getting only 69%.
The problem is on the all "if", when I test my test class Its ok, but the part of if's is not covering, it is not entering. I put the nessary data in the objects to pass in the if's but now I don't know what is missing.
I'm facing null pointer exception when I you add Opportuniyt id in every method. Now I updated my test class code, the method that is borken is key()
Also, I reviewed again that part and I got this error: "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object". It is the key method, the other method are ok but with this part all test class is wrong
If someone can help, pls. :)

**Controller Class**

```
public with sharing class CreateProjectController {    
    public static List<Opportunity> OpportunityList(String idOpportunity){
        List<Opportunity> opp = [SELECT Name, JiraProjectKey__c,ProjectName__c, AccountId,OpportunityTemplate__r.JiraProjectKey__c ,OpportunityTemplate__r.ProjectName__c, OpportunityTemplate__r.Name, Project__r.Id, Account.Name, Account.ProjectKey__c 
                                     FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: idOpportunity LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('OpportunityList : ' +opp);
        return opp;
    }
    
    public static List<Quote> QuoteList(String idOpportunity){
        List<Quote> quote = [SELECT Id, Name, Clarification__c 
                             FROM Quote WHERE OpportunityId =: idOpportunity AND IsSyncing=true LIMIT 1]; //Campo Sprints en Quote?
        System.debug('QuoteList: ' + quote);
        return quote;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String Scope(String idOpportunity){        
        List<Quote> quote = QuoteList(idOpportunity);
        String clarification;
        if(quote.size() > 0){
            clarification = quote[0].Clarification__c;
            System.debug('Scope : ' + clarification);
        }
        else{
            clarification = 'Null';
            System.debug('Error Campo scope ' + clarification);
            return clarification;
        }
        return clarification;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String Key(String idOpportunity){
        List<Opportunity> opp = OpportunityList(idOpportunity);
        String key;
        
        String nameAccount;
        String finalkeyAccount;
        
        String keyOpportunity;
        String finalkeyOpportunity;
            
        if(opp.size() > 0){      
            //NameAccount
            nameAccount = opp[0].Account.Name;            
            if(nameAccount.length() >= 5){
                finalkeyAccount = nameAccount.substring(0, 5);
            }
            else{
                finalkeyAccount = nameAccount;
            }            
            System.debug('key - finalkeyAccount : ' + finalkeyAccount);

            //KeyOpportunity
            keyOpportunity = opp[0].OpportunityTemplate__r.JiraProjectKey__c;            
            if(keyOpportunity.length() >= 5){
                finalkeyOpportunity = keyOpportunity.substring(0, 5);
            }
            else{
                finalkeyOpportunity = keyOpportunity;
            }
            System.debug('key - finalkeyOpportunity : ' + finalkeyOpportunity);
            //Key
            key = finalkeyAccount.toUpperCase() + finalkeyOpportunity.toUpperCase();
        }
        else{
            key = 'Null';
            System.debug('Error Campo key ' + key);
            return key;
        }
        System.debug('Key :' + key);
        return key;
    }
    
    public static String Name(String idOpportunity){
        List<Opportunity> opp = OpportunityList(idOpportunity);
        String name;
        
        String NameAccount;
        String ProjectName;
        
        String SubNameAccount;
        String SubProjectName;
        if(opp.size() > 0){
            
            NameAccount = opp[0].Account.Name;
            System.debug('Name - NameAccount : ' + NameAccount);
            
            ProjectName = opp[0].OpportunityTemplate__r.ProjectName__c;
            System.debug('Name - keyOpportunity : ' + ProjectName);
           
            name = NameAccount.toLowerCase() + '-' + ProjectName.toLowerCase();
        }
        else{
            name = 'Null';
            System.debug('Error Campo name ' + name);
            return name;
        }
        System.debug('Nombre : ' + name);
        return name;
    }
    
    /*
    public static String getContactId(String idOpportunity){
        List<Opportunity> opp = OpportunityList(idOpportunity);
        String IdContact;
        if(opp.size() > 0){
            String AccId = opp[0].AccountId;
            List<Contact> contact =  [SELECT Id, JiraUserID__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId =: AccId];
            IdContact = contact[0].Id;
        }
        System.debug('Contact Id: ' + IdContact);
        return IdContact;
    }
    */
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String CreateProject(String idOpportunity){        
        String statusProjecto = null;
               
        try{                        
            String name = Name(idOpportunity);
            System.debug('Name method value: ' + name);
            
            String scope = Scope(idOpportunity);
            System.debug('Scope method value: ' + scope);
            
            String key = Key(idOpportunity);
            System.debug('Key method value: ' + key);
            //String contactId = contactId(idOpportunity);
            
            Project__c project = new Project__c(); 
            project.Name = name;
            project.Scope__c = scope;
            project.Key__c = key;
            //project.ScrumMaster__c = contactId;
            insert project;
                
            String IdProjectCreated = project.Id;
            
            Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, Name, Project__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: idOpportunity LIMIT 1];
            if(project.Name != null && project.Key__c!= null && project.Scope__c != null){
                
                if(opp.Project__c == null){
                    opp.Project__c = IdProjectCreated;
                    update opp;
                        
                    statusProjecto = '1';
                    System.debug('Proyecto Creado');
                }else{
                    statusProjecto = '2';
                    System.debug('El proyecto ya existe en la oportunidad');
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            statusProjecto='3';
            System.debug('Tronó : ' + ex);
        }
        System.debug(statusProjecto);
        return statusProjecto; 
    }    
}
```

**Test class**

```
@isTest
public class CreateProjectControllerTest {
    @isTest
    static void testController(){
        //DATA
        Product2 product = new Product2(
            Name = 'Example Product',
            Description = 'This is the Product description.',
            ProductCode = 'EX1234',
            StockKeepingUnit = 'EX5678',
            Family = 'Example Product Family',
            QuantityUnitOfMeasure = 'inches',
            DisplayUrl = 'https://www.example.com/',
            ExternalId = 'ID #1234',
            IsActive = true);
        insert product;

        // Insert the Product in the Standard Price Book (if necessary)
        PricebookEntry standardPriceBookEntry = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
            Product2Id = product.Id,
            UnitPrice = 100.00,
            UseStandardPrice = false,
            IsActive = true);
        insert standardPriceBookEntry;
        
        // Create a Pricebook
        Pricebook2 priceBook = new Pricebook2(
            Name = 'Small Business Price Book',
            Description = 'This is the Price Book description.',
            IsActive = true);
        insert priceBook;

        // Insert the Product in the New Price Book
        PricebookEntry priceBookEntry = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = priceBook.Id,
            Product2Id = product.Id,
            UnitPrice = 100.00,
            UseStandardPrice = false,
            IsActive = true
        );
        insert priceBookEntry;
        
        Account account = new Account(
            Name='Test Account',
            Price_Book__c=priceBook.Id,
            NumberOfEmployees=20,
            Type='Customer',
            BillingStreet='av univ', 
            BillingCity='bj', 
            //BillingState='cdmx', 
            BillingCountry='Argentina', 
            BillingPostalCode='1704');
        insert account;
        
        Contact contact = new Contact(
            AccountId = account.Id,
            //Name = 'Name',
            LastName = 'Last Name',
            JiraUserID__c = 'un Id');
        insert contact;
        
        Project__c project = new Project__c(
            Name = 'name',
            Scope__c = 'scope',
            Key__c = 'KEYEXAMPLE',
            ScrumMaster__c = contact.Id);
        insert project;
        
        PopulateStage__c popStage = new PopulateStage__c(
            Stage__c = 'Discovery');
        insert popStage;
        
        Opportunity oppTemplate = new Opportunity(
            Name='Opportunity Template',
            StageName=popStage.Stage__c,
            PopulateFromTemplate__c = false,
            CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),
            AccountId=account.Id,
            Pricebook2Id=priceBook.Id,
            Product_Families__c='Salesforce Marketing Cloud',
            ProjectName__c = 'Nombre',
            RecordTypeId=Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Opportunity_Template').getRecordTypeId());
        insert oppTemplate;

        OpportunityLineItem cloneOpportunityLineItem = new OpportunityLineItem(
            OpportunityID=oppTemplate.Id,
            Quantity= 1,
            UnitPrice=1,
            Description='Prueba',
            Product2Id=product.Id,
            PricebookEntryId=pricebookEntry.Id);
        insert cloneOpportunityLineItem;      
        
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity (
            Name='Opportunity',
            //StageName='Discovery',
            CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),
            AccountId=account.Id,
            Pricebook2Id=priceBook.Id,
            Product_Families__c='Salesforce Marketing Cloud',
            JiraProjectKey__c = 'ASDF',
            PopulateFromTemplate__c = true,
            StageName = popStage.Stage__c,
            OpportunityTemplate__c = oppTemplate.Id,
            Project__c = project.Id);
        insert opp;
        
        Quote quotes = new Quote (
            Name = 'Quote Test',
            OpportunityId = opp.id , 
            Clarification__c='clarification', 
            Pricebook2Id = priceBook.Id,
            Footer__c='Footer'); 
        insert quotes;
        
        //set quote to isyncing by linking it to the opportunity
        opp.SyncedQuoteId = quotes.Id;
        //opp.Account.Name = 'Pruaisajd'; 
        update opp;
        
        

        Test.startTest();
            CreateProjectController.OpportunityList(opp.Id);
            System.debug('Opportunity List Method: ' + CreateProjectController.OpportunityList(opp.Id));
        
            CreateProjectController.QuoteList(opp.Id);
            System.debug('Quote List Method' + CreateProjectController.QuoteList(opp.Id));
        
            CreateProjectController.Scope(opp.Id);        
            CreateProjectController.Key(opp.Id);
            CreateProjectController.Name(opp.Id);
            //CreateProjectController.getContactId(opp.Id);
                
            CreateProjectController.CreateProject(opp.Id);
        Test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can I know is there any reason why you are passing empty string for the Scope(), Key() and Name() methods . If you pass the opportunity id I guess you will be able to cover the If blocks. Can you try this ?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Well, it doesn't matter I think, I dont know why I put these methods, maybe thats the error.
The last method "CreateProject" call the other methods in the class (key, name, scope), so I think is not nessesary.

Well, I tried and surely is nessesary
When I put the opp.Id in every method, I receive this error "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object" but it pass the if.
So, i'm stuck in the same, i don't what is missing and why if I put the method with "" as parameters are succesfull.

Comment: Please edit the question and mention the same that you are facing null pointer exception if you add Opportuniyt id

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala I already edit the question and the code, but I'm still getting the null pointer.... error. I associated the oppTemplated in the opp, also you can see in the post question. Thanks to your answer

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. I don't see JiraProjectKey__c for the oppTemplate record. In the code it is checking for opp[0].OpportunityTemplate__r.JiraProjectKey__c .

Comment: Yeahhh, it works! Thank you @SaiPraveenKakkirala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment try to pass the Opportunity id for the methods Scope(),Key() and Name().  As you confirmed in the comments You are getting NullPointer Exception if you are try to pass the opportunityid for the methods.

You need to modify your Apex class and also test class for that.

For the below line .

```
ProjectName = opp[0].OpportunityTemplate__r.ProjectName__c;
```

If there is no OpportunityTemplate__c for your opportunity then the above line causes Null pointer exception. I see the same issue with your test class your opportunity does not have OpportunityTemplate__c related to it. So you need your test data to relate it .

Also in the Apex class as well you have to check the null check where ever you are using the other object fields like above and also you have to handle the exception using try and catch block as per the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000327918&type=1).

This should resolve your issue.